# How to open .tif files in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know how I can open a .tif file in NetLogo 6.2?

I was using .asc files. But, for some reason, the conversion of files in .asc is giving a problem, which is not the case with files in .tif. So I would like to open files in .tif which is a map

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ Landcover ]
patches-own [ habitatcover ]
to setup
 
  set Landcover gis:load-dataset ( word "./L1_MAP.asc" ) 
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of Landcover 
  gis:apply-raster Landcover habitatcover 
  color-map
end

to color-map 
  ask patches [
    if habitatcover = 1 [ set pcolor orange + 2.9 ] 
    if habitatcover = 2 [ set pcolor orange - 2 ]  
  ]
end
```

I was using the code above to open .asc files. Now in .tif I thought I could use something like:

```
to setup 
  file-open "L2_MAP.tif"
  color-map
file-close      
end
```

But it did not work.can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As I read from the [GIS extension User Manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/gis.html#gis:load-dataset), unfortunately .tif is not among the supported types of data file.

(It is not clear to me if you're trying to import the map with the GIS extension? In the attempt that you showed with the .tif file, you are using `file-open` instead of any of the GIS extension's primitives. The `file-open` command [is not meant to help you deal with georeferenced files](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-open). Anyway, this shouldn't change the fact that .tif is not supported in NetLogo as far as I know)

Comment: Thanks Matteo. 
I sensed it. And I managed to adjust my .asc file. And I just solved this problem! Thank you for your help :)